# Enhancing Netdata Monitoring for Displaying Kubernetes Pod and Deployment Status

Tags: kubernetes, netdata, pods

After connecting netdata to my cluster, netdata begins to display the status of the nodes. But I would like to display the status of the pods. For example, I use nginx on my cluster. If you connect netdata to the server, then Nginx as a service will be displayed in the right column as a separate element. Is it possible to do this for all my pods or deployments. Or display them all in the nodes tab.

Unfortunately, GPT chat and Gemini do not provide anything useful.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions.